# Issue with Gitlab Runner for fastlane

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane, fastlane-match

[image]I am trying to run runner on gitlab which is config with Fastlane through a pipeline, when I commit pipeline runs but failed every time. I am not sure what is the issue but it seems that my gitlab-ic.yml file is not working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you installed java? Jdk or jre? Obviously your java path is wrong. You can post your config, so it is easier to find the problem.

Comment: yes, I did install java , jdk and jre are config correctly , because I have run a ruby server through java and It is working fine

Comment: This is issue with Gitlab

Comment: I have solved this issue by using a correct image for Android in config.yml file